# How do I print a cpu register to the screen?

Tags: linux, assembly, printing, x86-64, nasm

I think my loop is wrong and the `r10` register is not printing to the screen.

```
section .data

section .bss
know resd  16

section .text
   global _start         

    
_start:  

REDO:
   inc r10

   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov know, r10
   mov rcx, know        ; i want to print the r10 register to screen
   ;mov edx, 10
   int 0x80 

   mov rax, r10         ; here i want to compare 
   cmp rax, ffff        ; if r10 has reached ffff in its inc
   je END               ; jump out of loop if ffff is reached
   jmp REDO  

END:
```

What am I doing wrong here; do I have to put `r10` into a variable then put that in to `rcx` to
print it to screen; does `je` mean if `rax` equals ffff jump; do I have to put a x after ffffx

Comment: This won't even assemble (`mov know, r10` and undefined symbol/label `ffff`), but you didn't include the error messages from your [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to put a x after ffffx

If your 'ffff' is to be the hexadecimal representation of the number 65535, then write it as `0xFFFF`, prepending the `0x` hexadecimal prefix.

> does `je` mean if `rax` equals ffff jump

The `je` mnemonic stands for **J**umpIf**E**qual. Your code will jump if `rax` equals 0xFFFF.

> I think my loop is wrong ...

Good news: your loop is correct, but you could write it somewhat better:

- For testing the loop termination condition where `r10` equals 0xFFFF, you don't need to first copy `r10` to `rax`.
- And instead of exiting the loop on `r10 == 0xFFFF`, better continue the loop on `r10 != 0xFFFF`. It will save you from writing the extra unconditional `jmp`.

> ... and the `r10` register is not printing to the screen

For NASM, an instruction like `mov know, r10` makes no sense. In this instruction, *know* is merily an immediate number and it can't possibly be the destination of anything. You were trying to store the contents of the `r10` register in the buffer pointed at by *know*. The correct instruction would be `mov [know], r10` using the square brackets.
An instruction like `mov rcx, know` is fine since it moves an immediate number (the **address** of *know*) into the register. Immediates can be the source operand.

---

Displaying a number requires you to convert the binary value into a string of characters that represent decimal digits.
The following Q/A's explain the process:

- [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos)
- [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894)

The value in `r10` seems small enough, that we should not use the 64-bit division and instead use the faster 32-bit division:

```
know    resb 64
        ...

REDO:   inc  r10d

        mov  eax, r10d
        mov  ebx, know + 63  ; High up in the buffer
        mov  ecx, ebx
        mov  edi, 10         ; CONST
.more:  xor  edx, edx
        div  edi
        add  edx, '0'        ; Remainder [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
        mov  [rcx], dl
        dec  ecx
        test eax, eax
        jnz  .more
        mov  byte [rcx], ' ' ; Leading space

        sub  ebx, ecx        ; Number of digits
        lea  edx, [rbx + 1]  ; plus the leading space char
        mov  ebx, 1
        mov  eax, 4
        int  0x80

        cmp  r10d, 0x0000FFFF
        jne  REDO
END:
```

The leading space was added so that the numbers are not sticking together in this long series of numbers.

---

My previous answer [nasm linux x64 how do i find and cmp EOF to stop printing data from file to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100617/nasm-linux-x64-how-do-i-find-and-cmp-eof-to-stop-printing-data-from-file-to-scre/73129549#73129549)
already warned you about using `int 0x80` in 64-bit code. Today you still use it; was anything not clear from the link that I gave you?

```
know    resb 64
        ...

REDO:   inc  r12d

        mov  eax, r12d
        mov  rbx, know + 63  ; High up in the buffer
        mov  rsi, rbx
        mov  edi, 10         ; CONST
.more:  xor  edx, edx
        div  edi
        add  edx, '0'        ; Remainder [0,9] -> ["0","9"]
        mov  [rsi], dl
        dec  rsi
        test eax, eax
        jnz  .more
        mov  byte [rsi], ' ' ; Leading space

        sub  rbx, rsi        ; Number of digits
        lea  edx, [rbx + 1]  ; plus the leading space char
        mov  edi, 1
        mov  eax, 1
        syscall

        cmp  r12d, 0x0000FFFF
        jne  REDO
END:
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use the `int 0x80` 32-bit ABI in 64-bit code.  This code will break if linked into a PIE executable (so the address of `know` will be outside the low 32 bits, so `int 0x80` only looking at ECX as the address won't get a valid pointer).  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)